# Last inserted and updated row in mysql using NotORM

Tags: php, mysql, json, notorm

I need last inserted row using NotORM

```
$res=array("firstname"=>"fname","lastname"=>"lname");
$result = $db->Product()->insert($res);
$row=$db->product()->where('ProductId',$result['id'])->fetch();
echo json_encode($row);
```

output: false

database columns are id(auto_increment), firstname, lastname. And also i need last updated row. 
the above code doesn't work. please help

Comment: Welcome - please see how to ask - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Proof read before posting! - check your first line typo and typos in your title. "Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important! Remember, this is the first part of your question others will see - you want to make a good impression."

Comment: ´WHERE ProductId = ( SELECT MAX(ProductId) FROM Table)´
Should work else you order by DESC

Answer (score 1):

To get the last id inserted you need do this

```
$res=array("firstname"=>"fname","lastname"=>"lname");
$result = $db->Product()->insert($res);
echo $result["id"];
```

Warning independent of the name of your key in your database you use $result["id"] to obtain the value.

Like that you obtain the last id inserted

As far I can see in your example is fine you use it. I don't know if that affect but in your code the second time you put "product()" instead "Product()" also you should check if "ProductId" is typed right

Another thing that I think is if that return false is because json_encode return false that it's not the same that say that notorm return false, try print $row first before encode it.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following mysql query:

```
select last_insert_id();
```

It gives you back the last inserted_id. Put this in a transaction with the insert query to make it safe.